# Params.sort.key how does it works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can anybody using this in own projects? If yes, how? I know that it helps to minimize of attacks.

If I have in the following in my controller:

```
mail_id = params[:mail_id].to_i
user_id = params[:user_id].to_i
token = params[:token]
```

where should I write params.sort.key [and what i should write here?]

Comment: Where are you seeing `Params.sort.key` could you give us an example?

Comment: of course: for example: if params[:id] and params[:user_id] and params.key.sort == ['action', 'controller', 'id', 'user_id'] .. I saw this in one project

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to achieve? Also, your question is wrong when it says params.sort.key. As you have mentioned in the comment above, it can be params.keys.sort since params is a Hash. params.keys will be an array of all the keys in the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that concept should work as follows:

You expect 'params' hash to look somewhat like this:

```
params = { :mail_id => 1, :user_id => 2, :token => 'foo' }
```

which means params.keys will return [:mail_id, :user_id, :token]

params.keys.sort will return keys sorted alphabetically:
  [:mail_id, :token, :user_id]

So to verify if params are holding the exact keys you expect it to have, you can do:

```
    if params.keys.sort == [:mail_id, :token, :user_id]
       render :text => 'Serving your request'
    else
       render :text => 'Server understood the request, but refuses to serve it, since some of the requested data is missing'
    end
```

You can verify the exact contents of your 'params' hash using logger.debug(params.keys) in your controller